# What "modern" browsers does jScrollPane work consistently with?

Tags: jquery, mobile, jquery-jscrollpane

I read everywhere that jScrollPane "works consistently across all modern browsers". But never found what browsers and versions it actually implies.. I am basically looking at firefox, chrome and safari.

Also, the site should work well on mobiles. (iOS, Android)
Any guidance will help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used jScrollpane for at least 3-4 years now and from experience I can tell you that jscrollpane works perfectly in

- Internet Explorer 7 through 10
- Since Firefox 2 or 3
- Chrome pretty much since the beginning
- Safari (can't confirm which version but it worked 3-4 years ago so it's compatible with old versions)

In Webkit browsers CSS must be included before Javascript.

As for mobile, I can confirm that it works in iOS but sometimes the scrolling mechanism takes a couple of taps to activate.

Didn't have the chance to test on Android.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! Its this kind of an experience and information that I was looking for and dint find!